# Adobe Illustrator - How do I add the Indian Rupee Symbol?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, fonts, symbols

I can add a rupee symbol anywhere using the shortcut ₹ (CTRL+ALT+4) after selecting the Indian English Keyboard.

However, I am unable to do that in Adobe Illustrator.

How do I insert the Rupee symbol in Adobe Illustrator?

Comment: Hi Nildari Das, welcome to Graphic Design SE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Select the text tool;
2. Position your text cursor in the place that you want your currency symbol to be;
3. Open <kbd>Type > Glyphs</kbd>;
4. In the panel, scroll through your current typeface until you find your desired symbol;
5. Double-click the icon and it will appear in the place of your text cursor.

Also works for other symbols you can't type directly.

The Glyphs panel is also available in InDesign, where it has the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>.

The reason why your usual key combination doesn't work, is probably because Illustrator has another action assigned to it. You could try and look at <kbd>Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts</kbd> (<kbd>Alt/Option</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl/Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>) to find what function is linked to it and unlink it.

Answer (score 1):

- First, you need to use a font which has that symbol. A font may or
  may not have indian characters, and if it doesn't, no shortcut's
  going to work.
- Second, Windows shortcuts won't necessarily have the same effect in Illustrator. If that shortcut is assigned to some other action in Illustrator, or that character in that font file has a code assigned different than what the
  default code would be, again the shortcut's not going to work.
- Third, do what Vincent is saying, use the Glyphs panel and/or try to
  assign the shortcut manually.